# Can I configure a new remote site setting through apex code?

Tags: xcode, salesforce, integration

Is there a way to create a remote site setting through apex code?

> setup->new remote->name->url->active->save

These steps needed to create using remote site.

Comment: have you tired to do something

Comment: Please add what did you try already.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively. Remote site settings are part of system config (metadata) and most of these can't be modified by running inserts/updates/deletes from Apex. That would be dangerous. Imagine code that adds some malicious site (whitelists it), sends there some of your sensitive data and then deletes the setting...

There are hacks to call Metadata API, Tooling API etc things used during deployment. For example you could craft a REST callout that creates [RemoteProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_remoteproxy.htm) record (tooling API) or [RemoteSiteSetting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_remotesitesetting.htm) (metadata API). You could craft the XMLs yourself or look into Andy Fawcett's library for Apex calls to Metadata API: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi Haven't used it personally but I heard good stuff.

Sadly this is bit of chicken and egg situation - to make a callout to either API (even to "self", to this SF server you're already on) from Apex - you'd need an existing remote site setting or named credential. Again - Andy F. demonstrated a hack to make the first remote site from javascript. So it's not 100% automatic but well, visiting 1 config-like Visualforce page in every sandbox you need is not the end of the world...

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169381/tooling-api-calls-from-apex-requires-user-to-set-up-remote-site-settings
- https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/07/29/post-install-apex-metadata-api-configuration-solved/

Not sure why you tagged this [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode). I'm not a Mac person but if you're after automating something during deployments, quickly creating demo orgs/sandboxes with some scripts then maybe you should look into SF Ant Migration Tool or SFDX commands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with the Metadata Service API, which is very commonly used.
It is available from Salesforce [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls).  Doing so from within an async (ie `@future`) method allows you to do this from Aura or LWC as well.  If you don't wrap in a callout, you will get this error:

```
"FATAL_ERROR System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API faultcode=sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID faultactor="
```

Code below adapted from this [blog](https://www.biswajeetsamal.com/blog/tag/metadataservice/).

```
future(callout=true)
public static void createRemoteSite(String fullName, String url) {
    //Metadata Service
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

    //Metadata for remote site settings
    MetadataService.RemoteSiteSetting remoteSiteSettings = new MetadataService.RemoteSiteSetting();
    remoteSiteSettings.fullName = fullName;
    remoteSiteSettings.url = url;
    remoteSiteSettings.description = 'Remote site settings created from apex';
    remoteSiteSettings.isActive = true;
    remoteSiteSettings.disableProtocolSecurity = false;
    MetadataService.SaveResult[] results = service.createMetadata(
      new List<MetadataService.Metadata>{ remoteSiteSettings }
    );

    for (MetadataService.SaveResult result : results) {
      if (result.success) {
        //Success
        System.debug(result);
      } else {
        //Failed
        System.debug(result.errors[0].message);
      }
    }
  }
```

Information about the invalid session ID [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183578/how-do-i-call-the-salesforce-api-from-a-lightning-component).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to create a Remote Site Setting via Metadata API without MetadataService.

```
createRemoteSiteSetting(new Map<String, String>{
    'fullName' => 'TEST', // remote site setting name
    'description' => '', // description
    'url' => 'https://domain.invalid' // remote site URL      
});

/* SCRIPT */
final static String API_VERSION = '58';

public void createRemoteSiteSetting(Map<String, String> settingMap) {
    String endpoint = Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/m/' + API_VERSION + '/';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'create');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    String body = generateEnvelope(settingMap);
    System.debug(body);
    req.setBody(body);
    HttpResponse response = new Http().send(req);
    System.debug('response status code: ' + response.getStatusCode());
    System.debug('response: ' + response.getBody());
}

public String generateEnvelope(Map<String, String> settingMap) {
    return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
            '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:apex="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/08/apex" xmlns:cmd="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n' +
            '    <soapenv:Header>\n' +
            '        <cmd:SessionHeader>\n' +
            '            <cmd:sessionId>' + UserInfo.getSessionId() + '</cmd:sessionId>\n' +
            '        </cmd:SessionHeader>\n' +
            '    </soapenv:Header>\n' +
            '    <soapenv:Body>\n' +
            '        <create xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">\n' +
            '            <metadata xsi:type="RemoteSiteSetting">\n' +
            '                <fullName>' + settingMap.get('fullName') + '</fullName>\n' +
            '                <description>' + settingMap.get('description') + '</description>\n' +
            '                <disableProtocolSecurity>false</disableProtocolSecurity>\n' +
            '                <isActive>true</isActive>\n' +
            '                <url>' + settingMap.get('url') + '</url>\n' +
            '            </metadata>\n' +
            '        </create>\n' +
            '    </soapenv:Body>\n' +
            '</soapenv:Envelope>';
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).